# How include Node-sass options in VS Code task

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code, node-sass

I am compiling scss to css with [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass).
This works if I just manually type this in the terminal command line:

**This works**

```
node-sass --output-style compressed resources/assets/sass/sourcefile.scss public/css/endfile.css
```

But when I put the options in a [Visual Studio Code task](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) it doesn't work anymore. I supply the same arguments so I don't see why it wouldn't work...

**VS Code Task doesn't work**

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "node-sass",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["--output-style compressed","resources/assets/sass/materialize.scss","public/css/hrmaterialize.css"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate *--output-style* and *compressed*

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "node-sass",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args":  ["--output-style", "compressed","resources/assets/sass/materialize.scss","public/css/hrmaterialize.css"]
}
```